# How do I sync single folder on desktop in latest release of Google Drive

Tags: macos, google-drive-file-stream

Since Google Drive synch application tool "Backup" has been discontinued, I am forced to install "Google drive for Desktop".
I just want to synch my local folder to google drive. I found you can use a single folder using the option in google drive. But it is making other folders from my Google Drive in my local Mac.
I don't want any of my My Drive / My Unit folder in my local Mac, just one folder which synch with Drive.
I know the latest feature of stream occupies less space, but is there any way to altogether avoid it ?

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive for Desktop has two operating modes Mirror and Stream. In your case you should select **Stream**. You will see all the folders and files on My Drive / My Unit but don't worry as they are not being synced if you don't open them locally, they are just pointers to make it easier to download only the files that you need to view/edit locally.

If you want to sync only one folder, right click the folder and select **Available offline**.